# Mocking of url in unittest in python

Tags: python, python-unittest

i am pretty new to this
i have written below code for testing

```py
    def test_monthly_schedule(self):
        with patch('employee.requests.get') as mocked_get:
            mocked_get.return_value.ok = True
            mocked_get.return_value.text = "Success"

        schedule=self.e1.monthly_schedule()
        mocked_get.assert_called_with("http://www.google.com")

        self.assertEqual(schedule,"success")
```

this is for

```py
     def monthly_schedule(self):
        response=requests.get(f"http://www.google.com")
        if response.ok:
            return  response.text
        else:
            return "Bad response"
```

gets the error

```
    raise AssertionError('Expected call: %s\nNot called' % (expected,))
    AssertionError: Expected call: get('http://www.google.com')
    Not called
```

Comment: why are you mocking this?

    employee.requests.get

Answer (score 0):

Please note the code indentation.Use [patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) as context manager should work fine.

E.g.

`employee.py`:

```py
import requests


class Employee():
    def monthly_schedule(self):
        response = requests.get("http://www.google.com")
        if response.ok:
            return response.text
        else:
            return "Bad response"
```

`test_employee.py`:

```py
import unittest
from employee import Employee
from unittest.mock import patch


class TestEmployee(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.e1 = Employee()

    def test_monthly_schedule(self):
        with patch('employee.requests.get') as mocked_get:
            mocked_get.return_value.ok = True
            mocked_get.return_value.text = "Success"

            schedule = self.e1.monthly_schedule()
            mocked_get.assert_called_with("http://www.google.com")

            self.assertEqual(schedule, "Success")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
Name                                          Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/60680124/employee.py            7      1    86%   10
src/stackoverflow/60680124/test_employee.py      15      0   100%
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                            22      1    95%
```

Python version: `Python 3.7.5`